# flex 4.5 - dynamically autoAdjust horizontalAxis to specific visible values

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, charts, flex4.5, candlestick-chart

I'm currently building a CandlestickChart in flex 4.5. 
I have a large data set(~4500 candles) and I'm showing only 50 at time. 
My horizontalAxis is a `DateTimeAxis` and I've added scrolling to it.

My problem is that the autoAdjust property is adjusting according to my entire data set(~4500) and not to the visible data(~50 candles). 
I wish 2 things:

1. that the app will autoAdjust it to the viewable candles only
2. that the app will continue autoAdjusting while scrolling.

Does someone know if I can use the native autoAdjust or do I need to write new functionality to adjust the min-max properties on my own?

Open source solutions will be gladly excepted (:

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. i've implemented it myself. wasn't vary long after I made some modifications to the scrolling. just had to maintain a "lastCandleIndex" var and convert the scrolling to use candles indexes and their dates instead of increasing\decreasing the min\max values by time intervals so now the scrolling is not scrolling time intervals but a fixed number of candles. After implementing that, implementing the dynamic autoAdjust was fairly short and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. i've implemented it myself. wasn't vary long after I made some modifications to the scrolling. just had to maintain a "lastCandleIndex" var and convert the scrolling to use candles indexes and their dates instead of increasing\decreasing the min\max values by time intervals so now the scrolling is not scrolling time intervals but a fixed number of candles.

Comment: Never mind. i've implemented it myself. wasn't vary long after I made some modifications to the scrolling. just had to maintain a "lastCandleIndex" var and convert the scrolling to use candles indexes and their dates instead of increasing http://huntall.com/